# How to dismiss tabbed view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have problem withe dissmissing the tabbed view controller,can some body help.

Now coming to the processing steps.

1. My first viewcontroller is show in the fig below.
   [image: when I click any button I presenting the tabview controller]

   2.when I click any button I presenting the tabview controller
   [image]

3.When I go the camera tab the tabedview is like below 
[image]

4.when I press next I am presenting the view controller 
[image]

5.I this viewcontroller when I press Share button we have to dissmiss to tabbed viewcontroller i.e 1sttab in the tabeedview controller.show in the fig below [image]

Waiting for the quick Responce  and any is help is appreciated.

Comment: You want to dismiss the presented view controller when somebody clicks on the share button?

Comment: Thanks for quick responce.yes when somebody clicked on the share button I have to dismiss

Comment: then you should call the dissmissViewController method.. is it not working?

Comment: @saurabh Thanks for the Responce,I called dismiss view controller but I am going to tabview where I am presenting I.e camera tab but I want to go to the Home tab

Comment: If you will dismiss Tabbed view controller on the share button click, it means you want to appear very first controller? If this is the case then instead of dismissing tabbed view controller you can present your first controller.

Comment: [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];

Comment: If you just want to go to Home tab then add this line 
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];

Comment: @SatheeshkumarNaidu plz check my answer

Comment: @SatheeshkumarNaidu You should dismiss the view controller without animation.

Comment: @saurabh jain I tryed with animation noe I will try with out animation

Comment: @surabh jain for images it is good but in care of url sharing i.e video sharing is very slow.after pressing share button it is going to the camera tab after 5to 7 sec it is going to the home

Comment: @minkel sorry for the delay I have done this but it is taking time.

Comment: @SatheeshkumarNaidu try to share the data on background or you can also use NSNotificationCenter

Comment: I done that but this the problem when i pass the image array the time period is improved no problemi.e_finalvideourl is 0, but when _finalvideourl is 1 then is is taking time of 6 to 8 sec

Comment: Then you must call the method when sending data method has been  finished @SatheeshkumarNaidu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the selectedIndex property of tab bar controller to solve your issue

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
```

--

Try this

```
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ShareArray" object:_selectedimgarray]; 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SharetitleArray" object:_newtile]; 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"sharevideooutputurl" object:_finalvideourl]; 
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
        });
            }];
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick responce ,Now I am using same - (IBAction)sharebuttn:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
         //  Tabbar index
  
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ShareArray" object:_selectedimgarray];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SharetitleArray" object:_newtile];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"sharevideooutputurl" object:_finalvideourl];
         [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
    }];
    
}

Comment: the problem with this is when I press the share button first it is dismissing  to the camera tab and then it is going to the home tabb,

Comment: while I am going back I am passing images and videos I.e images in the array and the video in the url formate,when i pass the image array it is quick when i pass the video url it is very slow

Comment: @SatheeshkumarNaidu - try putting your completion handler code inside dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // here});

Comment: my completion handler is [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
         //  Tabbar index
  
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ShareArray" object:_selectedimgarray];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SharetitleArray" object:_newtile];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"sharevideooutputurl" object:_finalvideourl];
         [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
    }];
how to modify ths

Comment: @SatheeshkumarNaidu -  Try my updated answer. This method -"Submits a block for asynchronous execution on a dispatch queue and returns immediately."

Comment: done same thing by see your comment,when i pass the image array the time period is improved no problemi.e_finalvideourl is 0, but when _finalvideourl is 1 then is is taking time of 6 to 8 sec

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for your problem. Please try this code to dismiss the view controller if you present the view using modal:
//Swift

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {});
```

//Objective C

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

In the completion handler do something like this to change the tab bar index:

```
NSInteger indexOfTabToSwitchTo = 1//Change this number according to your preference of controller
[self.presentingViewController.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:indexOfTabToSwitchTo];
```

/. Combined together may be it'll look something like this

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    NSInteger indexOfTabToSwitchTo = 1//Change this number according to your preference of controller
    [self.presentingViewController.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:indexOfTabToSwitchTo];
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer.I am not using  segue,If I use this [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];   I am going back to the tabviewcontroller from where I am presenting the viewcontroller i.e camera tab but I want to dismiss to the Home tab.

Comment: Updated answer. Set index number as per your controller to which you want to switch to

Comment: If you presentingViewController,i Have one problem,When go from share to home I am passing 2arrays and one url for this I am using nsnotification center ,so if i do this notification is calling 2 times and the in home tab view did load is again calling

Comment: After passing the videourl i want play to it the collection view cell how to do that,note:the cellready contains images,now i want to add video with images on the image view

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
     [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];   
    }];
```

Comment: I have already done this but it is gongback to the camera tab and then hoome tab

Comment: After passing the videourl i want play to it the collection view cell how to do that,note:the cellready contains images,now i want to add video with images on the image view